# jQuery - 'addClass' to HTML element - not working but shown correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

In a nutshell, I'm trying to add a class using jQuery's `addClass` to an HTML element that has the class `button-blue`. Unfortunately, it's not working. I replaced `addClass` with `attr` but that didn't work either.

In Chromium (latest version, 64-bit, Ubuntu), the added class `selected` is successfully added to the `button-blue` element if I state `"selected"` but not for `".selected"` - with prefixed dot.

Also, this has not been resolved when stating `.button-blue` in my javascript file.

Demo in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qijoxe/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

Some help and, if available, some resources where I can emerge into the correct syntax are definitely appreciated.

Thanks,
J

HTML code

```
<body>
<div id="switcher">
  <div class="button-blue">Blue menu1</div>
  <div class="button-red">Red menu2</div>
  <div class="button-green">Green menu3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS code

```css
.button-blue {
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.selected {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: black;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button-blue').addclass('selected');
});
```

Comment: use `.button-blue` inside jquery selector

Comment: I have tried that already, it's not working. You can try it on JSBin. The console is spitting out an error message.

Comment: Typo: `addclass` should be `addClass` and your demo isn't loading jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-blue').addClass('selected');
});
```

`.button-blue` andd `addClass` instead `addclass`

[Here's a JS Bin example as well.](http://jsbin.com/pisobu/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
$('button-blue').addclass('selected');
```

use the correct selector (also note `addClass` is *camelCase*):

```
$('.button-blue').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tried that already, but that is not working. Also, is there a good explanation why `.button-blue` has to be with a dot but `selected` is without a dot? Can the dot be omitted when using `addClass`?

Comment: I'm not sure if case matters but in the docs the function is `.addClass` instead of `.addclass` https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Yes, it matters, JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Hmm, tried that. Not working either.

Comment: @johann_ka "." means a class so no you cannot omit this. This $('.button-blue') stands for DOM elements that have the class "button-blue". If your div has an id, you can use a "#" instead of a "."

Comment: But why is the dot omitted in `selected`?